# MDX ParallelPeriod with multiselect date values in excel 2010 pivot table

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel-2010, mdx, ssas-2012

I have created a calculated measure via `"New Calculated Member"` in a Visio Studio 2010 cube project

The expression is as follows:

```
[Measures].[Extended Price],
PARALLELPERIOD([Dim Calendar].[RetailCalendar].[Retail Year], 1,[Dim Calendar].[RetailCalendar].currentmember)
```

This uses the Dim Calendar hierarchy RetailCalendar:

```
Retail Year,
Retail Quarter,
Retail Month,
Retail Week,
Retail Day
```

When using this measure, Sales LY, in an Excel 2010 pivot table, it works as long as only one member of the date hierarchy is select.

```
eg. Retail Year 2016 only
eg. Retail Week 2016 24 only.
```

How can I write this calculation so that it allows multiple dates selected?

After searching for solutions, I got as far as:

```
aggregate
(
    Generate(
        existing [Dim Calendar].[RetailCalendar].[PK Date].members,
        (PARALLELPERIOD(
            [Dim Calendar].[RetailCalendar].[Retail Year], 1,[Dim Calendar].[RetailCalendar].currentmember
            )
        )
    ,[Measures].[Extended Price])
)
```

which results in `null`

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is now pretty old and hopefully you've found your answer now! I was having the exact same issue and I thought I'd post my solution to help anyone else searching.

First step - You need to create a Dynamic set, within your cube's MDX script, for the Date dimension. i.e.

```
CREATE 
 DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[Dates Selected] AS          
           EXISTING [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Date];
```

Second step - Obtain the Head(first) and Tail(last) of the dynamic set. The two functions generate the result as a tuple so we'll need to use .Item(0) to extract the member part i.e.

```
HEAD([Dates Selected],1).Item(0)
TAIL([Dates Selected],1).Item(0)
```

These can be used with Range and in combination with PARALLELPERIOD and SUM to obtain the results i.e.

```
CREATE 
 MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Extend Price Prev Period] AS          
           SUM (
                    {
                        PARALLELPERIOD([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],1,HEAD([Dates Selected],1).Item(0))
                        :
                        PARALLELPERIOD([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],1,TAIL([Dates Selected],1).Item(0))
                       }
                ,[Measures].[Extend Price]);
```

I hope this helps!